# Is there a way to configure multiple gradle tasks at once?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have the following snippet in a `build.gradle` file for a project I work on:

```
tasks.named('test').configure {
    dependsOn customTask
}

tasks.named('compileTestJava').configure {
    dependsOn customTask
}

tasks.named('jar').configure {
    dependsOn customTask
}

tasks.named('build').configure {
    dependsOn customTask
}
```

It seems redundant to have to specify the the same configuration for 4 tasks separately. Is there a way to select and configure multiple tasks at once? Perhaps something like:

```
tasks.named('test', 'compileTestJava', 'jar', 'build').configure {
    dependsOn customTask
}
```

(I tried this code, but it does not work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].each {
   tasks.named(it).configure {
      dependsOn 'customTask'
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the source code we have the method `named(Spec<String> nameFilter)`. This is configuration avoidance API.

Example:

```
tasks.named { it in ['a', 'b', 'c'] }.configureEach {
     dependsOn 'customTask'
}
```